# How to add commit message from command prompt on windows

Tags: git, vim

I am trying to add a commit message from the command line on my windows10 PC. I have done the following:

1. typed in `git commit` from the command line.
2. in the vim interface I typed in the commit subject and description.
3. hit the `esc` key then typed in `wq` but the vim interface doesn't exit.
   When I closed it and tried to push to github it doesn't push. I tried the above again but the vim interface doesn't exit. What am I getting wrong or what do I need to do to make the vim interface exit, cause the commit to be done so I that I can push to github?

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the `:` in `:wq`? And you need to press "Return" after `:wq`.

Comment: Consider the [vi.se] stack for questions on Vim!

Comment: Thanks I was missing the :... it's supposed to be :wq not wq

Comment: Don't worry, you're not alone... How to quit Vim is one of the most popular questions of all time! 

Answer (score 1):

try to use:
git commit -m "My commit message"

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a commit message.

1. type in `git commit` from the command line or terminal.
2. a vim interface appears. in the vim interface, type in the commit subject and description.
3. hit the `esc` key then type in `:wq` and hit the `enter` key to exit the vim interface.